# How to resolve an error while restoring database from mysql dump file

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql database dump file, while restoring database from this file, i am getting an error like below

```
 Database Restore Wizard: Error (102,1): 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''%PDF-1.4\r%âãÏÓ\r\n6 0 obj <</Linearized 1/L 139168/O 8/E 135033/N 1/T 1390' at line 1
```

The error occurs while inserting file as blob type. the causing the error is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3uU23D89jnGWTJnRnJiYkhxejQ/edit?usp=sharing)

How to resolve this error.

Comment: If you have a corrupted dump with binary files I don't think you'll be able to fix it with a text editor. Whatever, any chance to see the offending code?

Comment: sure here https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3uU23D89jnGOE5XU2lpOGpiNmM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you please edit the question (you can use the "edit" link right below), paste the SQL query the error message complains about and format it as code with the `{}` toolbar button? The site guidelines state that questions should be self contained.